# Django login from wordpress using oauth2

Tags: django, wordpress, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

I'm stuck on working out a secure approach but this is what I would like to achieve:

1. User is in Wordpress
2. User from wordpress logs into django and requests a token (preferably oauth2)
3. Token is stored
4. Token is used for api calls to my django site

How can someone programatically request a token from django whilst in wordpress? Anything to point me in the right direction is much appreciated!

Comment: Where are you stuck actually? Have you created additional link into wordpress admin menu (the right side list) already? Have you created page, that opens when you click that link?

Comment: I have options for my plugin available and can definitely save a token in there, the place im really stuck is how to make the actual call to my django site securely and retrieve an oauth token

Comment: Php has libraries for making such calls. Look up some php oauth library for that. Include it in your project and voila. If you want to do it securely, then use https instead of http.

Comment: thanks for the direction on a rookie question. With regards to using https does that also mean I have to buy an ssl cert?

Comment: Nope. Google - "how to generate self signed ssl certificate"

Comment: Thanks heaps for all the direction, didn't even know you could create self signed certificates

Comment: No problem. Have fun :)